# How does WordPress back up and save a post when disconnected?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, caching

Has anyone encountered this when saving a WordPress post/page?

`"Connection lost. Saving has been disabled until you’re reconnected. We’re backing up this post in your browser, just in case."`

I'm interested in what kind of tools WordPress uses to cache data. What did they mean by: `saving into XML in browser cache?` Raw data? Or another technology?

Can all browsers do that?

I've searched online for answers but have not found anything helpful.

Comment: not php. Wordpress's php displays a regular html frontend / dashboard, which in turn has common js to interact with browser's localstorage.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm interest what kind of tech wp use for backup the data into browser, specially using php.

None.  PHP runs server-side.  It doesn't run in the browser.

What you're looking for is HTML5 Local Storage.  You can store strings, or even put stuff into a small database.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

This is well supported by many browsers:  http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage